# summation or sorting

Tags: awk, grep

I have a data file like:

```
82 DEX26_28_h
82 DEX26_28_h
873 DEX34_h
89 DEX37_h
1 DEX34_h
```

And I intend to sort via $2 so that each item (17 uniques) in column to are next to each other. Then I would like to sum up all #'s in $1 while tethered to $2

ideal result of test file above :

```
164 DEX26_28_h
874 DEX34_h
89 DEX27_h
```

Make sense?  Basically need to sum up the total number of sequences ($1) that occur for each sample ($2) and uniq only $2 while keeping the sum. So that the end result becomes 17 total lines.

Should I just grep out by each of the 17 Identifies in $2 and then sum them using awk ?

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array in awk to do the summation:

```
awk '{arr[$2]+=$1} END {for (i in arr) {print arr[i],i}}'
```

Then you can pipe it to sort afterwards.

---

What this does:

- `arr[$2]+=$1`: Adds the value of `$1` to the element in the array `arr` with index (key) `$2`. (Previously undefined elements are conveniently defined as 0 for you so yes, you can do a `+=` here without worrying if the key "exists" or not.) If you're unfamiliar with arrays, this is basically creating a lookup table in memory based on your `$2` field.
- `END...`: Do this once at the end of processing
- `for (i in arr)`: For every key in the array `arr`, assign that element to `i` and run the code in the following block.
- `print arr[i],i`: Prints first the value in `arr` with key `i`, then the key `i` itself.

Comment: > :D   awesome! Mind helping me understand your script more?  I can read up on arr myself.  but you syntax is interesting.  does the brackets in [$2]  mean all within $2?   and I assume the "i" variable is created in the arr ?

Comment: @jon_shep Sure, I added some explanatory text to my answer

Comment: lc.  Thank you! practice makes perfect for me.